# MongoDB Multiple Projection - Performance and memory usage

Tags: mongodb, localization, query-optimization

I am trying to find a suitable structure for my MongoDB documents that contains localization support. To simplify my case, let's assume that we have 10000 documents where each document in the collection consists of properties that have localization support for over 150 languages represented as language codes. In the real scenario, the document would contain multiple sub-documents also.

**Example of a document where all properties are localized:**

```
{
    "_id": "61a8cbb19a398cd2531b515e",
    "property1": {
        "eng-us": "translation text",
        "eng-uk": "translation text",
        "ekk": "translation text",
        "fra-fr": "translation text",
        "fra-ca": "translation text"
        ... +150 other languages 
    },
    "property2": {
        "eng-us": "translation text",
        "eng-uk": "translation text",
        "fra-fr": "translation text",
        "fra-ca": "translation text"
        ...+150 other languages
    },
    .. +20 other properties
}
```

Now let's assume that everytime I fetch this document, I would only need one or two languages for each property. For instance, I only want "eng-us" for all the properties that has localization support. Which in turn would result after a projection to the following document.

```
db.find( { _id: "61a8cbb19a398cd2531b515e" }, { "property1.en-us": 1, "property2.en-us": 1, ...+20 other properties }
```

Would as result return the following document:

```
{
    "_id": "61a8cbb19a398cd2531b515e",
    "property1": {
        "eng-us": "translation text",
    },
    "property2": {
        "eng-us": "translation text"
    },
    .. +20 other properties with only "eng-us" property
}
```

**Question:**

- If I would execute multiple projections in this way, how would such an operation influence the performance and memory usage of the MongoDb server compared with just returning the document without projections?
- Is there any other methods that I should consider that could significantly improve the performance and memory of fetching documents with such structure?

Comment: You could do better with a structure which allows indexing on the data you are querying. Indexing can make your queries perform faster -  even with large amount of documents. For example, you could have the data as an array: `translations: [ { lang: "eng-us", text: "translslated text en" } , { lang:  "fra-ca", text: "..." }, ... ]`. Then index on the "translations.lang" array field. And, then query or perform projections.

Comment: That sounds like a potential fix. However due to my limited understanding of the internal process of MongoDB my primary concern is that by finding the first element that matches the language code and then converting that first element match to an object seems to be expensive in terms of CPU and memory usage along with operation time. Is this the case?

Comment: You will be matching using the index on the `translations.lang` field (as I had mentioned in the previous comment) - thats the advantage. You can get familiar with the filtering and projecting array fields with embedded documents (see [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)).

Comment: Thank you. However, it seems like I would still need to run an aggregation on the results since `$elemMatch` can only filter the array to one element at most. For my understanding, running an aggregation pipeline compared with find projection using elemMatch seems to be inefficient in terms of both performance and maintenance (a lot of code is required to construct a project.filter.or pipeline aggregation on each property)